# How to count foreign key objects with annotation in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

**Hi all!**

*New in Django, and confused, help is appreciated!*

Have three models:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    organization_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class AppealForm(models.Model):
    form_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Appeal(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    appeal_form = models.ForeignKey(AppealForm, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    applicant_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

Objects of **Organization** model:

| organization_name |
| --- |
| Organization 1 |
| Organization 2 |

Objects of **AppealForm** model:

| form_name |
| --- |
| In written form |
| In oral form |

Objects of **Appeal** model:

| organization | appeal_form | applicant_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Organization 1 | In written form | First and Last name |
| Organization 1 | In oral form | First and Last name |
| Organization 1 | In oral form | First and Last name |
| Organization 2 | In written form | First and Last name |
| Organization 2 | In oral form | First and Last name |

*I'm trying to create a table in the template, like:*

| Organization | Total amount of appeals | Amount of written form appeals | Amount of oral form appeals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Organization 1 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| Organization 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

The content in the table contents has to be retrieved from Appeal model, that is rendered to the template.

**Question:**
How the query look like in views.py using Appeal model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i recommend you read about how to do complex query in django from this [documents](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/) section.
Here what your query would be like:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Case, When, IntegerField

Appeal.objects
      .values('organization')
      .annotate(
          total_appeals=Count('appeal_form'), 
          written_amount=Count(Case(
                When(appeal_form__form_name="In written form", then=1),
                output_field=IntegerField(),
          )),
          oral_amount=Count(Case(
                When(appeal_form__form_name="In oral form", then=1),
                output_field=IntegerField(),
          )),
       ).order_by()
```

set the above query to a value and loop through it and see the results. You should get something like this

> [{'organization': 'Organization 1', 'total_appeals': 3,
> 'written_amount': 1, 'oral_amount': 2},   {'organization':
> 'Organization 2', 'total_appeals': 2, 'written_amount': 1,
> 'oral_amount': 1}]

Explanations:

- values to group by `organization`
- `Count` to count the form in that organization group
- we use `Case` to add an `if condition`, then=1 to return value(else return null)
- the written_amount need to be integer so we set it in the `output_field`

conditional part in the documents https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions

why you should use order_by() for grouping queries https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-order-by

Comment: Hi @LinhNguyen! Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Using this query, I am getting separately total amount depending on appeal_form, not one row :( It is not grouped per organization...

Comment: @jSCTPP hi i  updated  my  answer, try adding order_by() at the end of the query and see if the results are corrected

Comment: You are my hero!)

Comment: glad it helped you